# ASP.NET: RegisterStartupScript does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to run a client-side script from the server-side on **Page_Load**, I found this code from [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/01/execute-javascript-function-from-aspnet.html). 
It's server side code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("alert"))
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
            "alert", "alertMe();", true);
    }
}
```

And it's client side code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertMe() {
        alert('Hello');
    }
</script>
```

But nothing happens on **Page_Load**.

**UPDATE**: source code [coderun](http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=XjaajP8oG0u2H_xBeiZmBw).

Comment: Where you have script block containing definition of alertMe function?

Comment: @Adil it's in .aspx file

Comment: Yes I should be, is it in head, before closing body tag or after body closing tag?

Comment: @Adil it's in body tag, before closing tag.

Comment: It should have worked then, try putting in head tag or try calling the function after its definition 
function alertMe() {
        alert('Hello');
    }
alertMe()

Comment: Your code works - I just tried it now

Comment: @codingbiz Yes, when I put it in head tag it works. Write it as answer then I'll mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your `alertMe()` before it is defined, at the end of the page.

All scripts registered with asp.net are rendered in the form tag.

I suggest moving your javascript block to the head of the page.

```
<head runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function alertMe() {
      alert('Hello');
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Here is your [modified code run](http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=6SqHJA1PNEO0ZvFyjOAazA) that works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check two things

1. Is your js function is not in some other function. Then it is not visible for server
2. Is html tag which contain your script has `runat="server"` tag.

In your case:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function alertMe() {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    </script>
</head>
```